# Alexa Nodejs Skill - Second Intent asked always fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I've started making a simple Alexa skill with CodeStar and Nodejs, my skill can inform the user about whether a Web system is currently still available, if there are any current incidents or service outtages. I get all the data in the form of a JSON API from http://statuspage.io.

The issue I'm having is that, my `LaunchRequestHandler` works correctly and also so does the first Intent that I ask, however when I ask a second intent (immediately after the first intent) this is where my Skill breaks and outputs (inside the Alexa Developer Console): `<Audio only response>`.

[image: Alexa Developer Console Screenshot]

Below I've pasted the code I have within my Skill.

```
// model/en-GB.json

"intents": [{
    "name": "QuickStatusIntent",
    "slots": [],
    "samples": [
        "quick status",
        "current status",
        "tell me the current status",
        "what's the current status",
        "tell me the quick status",
        "what's the quick status"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "CurrentIncidentIntent",
    "slots": [],
    "samples": [
        "incidents",
        "current incident",
        "is there a current incident",
        "tell me the current incidents",
        "what are the current incidents",
        "are there any current incidents"
    ]
}]


// lambda/custom/index.js

const QuickStatusIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
      return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'QuickStatusIntent';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
      let speechText = await getNetlifyStatus();
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText)
        .getResponse();
    }
};

const CurrentIncidentIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'CurrentIncidentIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const result = await getSummary();
    const speechText = `There are currently ${result.incidents.length} system incidents`;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
}
```

My initial thought was to remove the `.getResponse()` as that might have been waiting for a response, however, that didn't seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your **CurrentIncidentIntentHandler** closes the session right after delivering the response to user.

If you want to keep the session **open** and let user to carry on the conversation Use `.withShouldEndSession(false)` or `.repeat(speechText)` in your **CurrentIncidentIntentHandler** to make Alexa wait for the user's next response.

```js
const CurrentIncidentIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'CurrentIncidentIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const result = await getSummary();
    const speechText = `There are currently ${result.incidents.length} system incidents`;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withShouldEndSession(false) //you can also use .repeat(speachText) at this line
      .getResponse();
  }
}
```